# How to prevent a div from overflowing on the other one

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

The only issue that I have with following header is that by changing the screen size,the two buttons overlap the search button. I need them to stay where they are and in small screens that there is not enough space to have the search box and buttons in a horizontal line. The two buttons jump up. Right below the three small images.

I removed some css stylings that were not related to the question to simplify the code.

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/jackmoore/qmfanyqf/)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

<link rel="stylesheet"
    href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet"
    href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">


<link rel="stylesheet"
    href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet"
    href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-social/4.2.1/bootstrap-social.css">

<style>

html, body {
    height: 100%;
}

body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.show-xs {
    display: none;
}

@media ( max-width : 480px) {
    .top-center {
        width: 100%;
    }
    .top-right {
        padding-bottom: 4px;
    }

    #logo {
        width: 120%;
    }
    .btn-search {
        float: right;
    }
    .login {
        margin-left: 10px;
        margin-right: -23px;
    }
    .show-xs {
        display: block;
    }
    .hide-xs {
        display: none;
    }
}

body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

* {
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.top-part {
    width: 100%;
    background-color: green;
}

.top { 
    max-width: 1509px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;
}

.top-center {
    display: inline-block; 
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

.top-right {
    display: inline-block;
    float: right;
    height: 100%;
    margin-right: 3%; //
    width: 200px; //
    padding-left: 20px;
}

.left-part {
    float: left;
    height: 100%;
    margin-left: 6%;
    margin-top:-0.3%;
    width: 7%;
}

.middle-part {
    width: 82%;
    float: left;
    height: 100%;
    text-align: left;
}

.logo {
    text-align: left;
    padding-bottom:3px;
    padding-top:7px;
}

.login {
    text-align: left;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
    .top-center {
        width: 100%;
    }
}

.left-part img {
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
    padding: 2px;
    margin-top: 9px;
}

.logo img { //
    height: 40px;
    width: 70%;
    max-width: 90%;
    display: inline-block;
}

.login input, .login button {
    display: inline-block;
}

.login input {
    width: 44%;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
    .login input {
        width: 100%;
    }
}

.social ul {
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
}

.social li {
    height: 30px;
    width: 30px;
    float: right;
    background-color: blue;
    margin-left: 4px;
    margin-top: 4px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
}

.social li a {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

.social1 {
    background-image:
        url();
}

.social2 {
    background-image:
        url();
}

.social3 {
    background-image:
        url();
}

.mybuttons {
    margin-top: -63px;
    float: right;
    padding: 0;
}

.mybuttons a {
    display: inline-block;
}


.btn-search {
    background-color: green;
    border-style: none;
}

.myBtns {
    border-style: outset;
    color: black;
    background-color: green;
    border-color: gray;
    border-width: 1px;
    padding: 2px 7px 3px 13px;
}

.myBtns:hover {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;
    cursor: pointer;
}

</style>
</head>
<body>

<header>
    <div class="top-part">
        <div class="left-part show-xs">
            <img
                src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcR4Aa9iHfxi_6jmKGL8stVsrJ98FBVmy5DK9c6BsGHweaQ5PBoc"
                id="logo">
        </div>
        <div class="logo show-xs">
            <img
                src="https://pixabay.com/static/uploads/photo/2012/05/07/18/44/banner-48962_640.png">
        </div>
        <div class="top-right">
            <div class="social">
                <ul>
                    <li class="social3"><a href="www.googleplus.com"></a></li>
                    <li class="social2"><a href="www.twitter.com"></a></li>
                    <li class="social1"><a href="http://www.facebook.com"></a></li>
                </ul>

            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="top">
            <div class="top-center">
                <div class="left-part hide-xs">
                    <img id="logo" src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcR4Aa9iHfxi_6jmKGL8stVsrJ98FBVmy5DK9c6BsGHweaQ5PBoc" />
                </div>
                <div class="middle-part">
                    <div class="logo hide-xs">
                        <img src="https://pixabay.com/static/uploads/photo/2012/05/07/18/44/banner-48962_640.png" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="login">
                        <form>
                            <input id="searchType" type="hidden" name="searchType"
                                value="">
                            <input id="searchTerm" name="searchTerm"
                                class="form-control myInput" type="text" value="" />
                            <input id="searchBox2" name="searchBox2" class="form-control myInput"
                                type="text" value="" />
                            <button class="btn-search" type="submit" title="Search">
                                <div style="background-color: green;">
                                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"
                                        style="font-size: 20px;"></span>
                                </div>
                            </button>
                        </form>
                        <div id="msg" class="msg">
                            <p>Message goes here</p></div>
                    </div>

                </div>

                    <div class="mybuttons">
                        <a id="Btn1" class="myBtns" >BTN1BTN1</a> 
                        <a id="Btn2" class="myBtns">BTN2BTN2</a>
                    </div>
            </div>

        </div>

    </div>

</header>

</body>


</html>
```

Comment: You forgot to mention what you want to achieve..

Comment: I'm still not sure what the OP is asking for. @Jack where/how do you actually want those two buttons positioned? I see them both inline with each other, to the right of two text boxes. Should they be like that, only positioned beneath the right-most text box?

Comment: @takiMartillo In large screens, the should be on the right side of the search boxes, in small screens that width is shorter, they should be under those three small images.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To achieve your desired layout, you need to display both the `.login` form and the `.mybuttons` as `inline-block` within the same parent container.  If you add container divs to the `.login` and `.mybuttons`, you can do this pretty easy.

Here's your updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qmfanyqf/4/).

**Explanation**:

In your markup, I am putting both areas within the `.middle-part` div and adding containers to set as `display: inline-block`.

```
<div class="middle-part">
    ...

    <div class="login-outer>
        <div class="login">
          (put your login <form> and <inputs> here)                    
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="buttons-outer">
        <div class="mybuttons">
            <a id="Btn1" class="myBtns" >BTN1BTN1</a> 
            <a id="Btn2" class="myBtns">BTN2BTN2</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Then in your css:

```
// set both containers to inline-block
.login-outer, .buttons-outer      
{
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
}
// Specify breakpoint widths. When there isn't enough space
// to display these widths in the same line, they will stack instead.
.login-outer
{ 
    min-width: 500px;  // or whatever
}
.buttons-outer 
{ 
    min-width: 190px;
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: The issue is solved thanks, but in small size screens the search button gets disappeared.

Comment: Hey Jack, I've updated the fiddle to accommodate the search button.  In your stylesheet, you can tweak the <input> widths and the .login-outer and .buttons-outer min-widths to dial in the style you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

plz make sure to use the correct structure of bootstrap.
You can use col-md-12 or col-sm-12 etc according to the screen sizes you want.

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
       <div class="mybuttons">
            <a id="Btn1" class="myBtns" >BTN1BTN1</a> 
            <a id="Btn2" class="myBtns">BTN2BTN2</a>
        </div>
</div>
```

You can look for tutorials at http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/ 
This is the best site forlearning bootstrap. 
Grid system in Bootstrap: http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-example-basic

Answer (score -1):

You need to remove the margin-top: -63px; on .mybuttons To stop the overlap.

If you are using bootstrap you can look into push pull to move objects around on a smaller screen size.

You could also repeat the buttons and show/hide them depending on which media query size you are at.

Comment: If I remove margin-top how am I supposed to have the buttons in a correct position?

Answer (score -2):

You can avoid over flow by using following code in your html page

```
<div style="overflow:hidden;">
Your code here
  </div>
```

To hide overflow

Comment: Probably best to avoid inline styling.